# Javascript Replace adds several <br />'s to beginning and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Javascript to add `<br />` in between every letter of text in a tag. Code is as follows:

```
$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(.{1})/g, "$1<br />"));
```

It's adding several extra `<br />` tags to the beginning and end of the string, so instead of turning `Asia` into

`A<br />s<br />i<br />a`

I end up with

`<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />A<br />s<br />i<br />a<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />`

Help!

Edit: There are no leading or trailing spaces. It's simply `<h1>Asia</h1>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `.` which matches any character, if you're after letters why not do something like:

```
$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(\w{1})/g, "$1<br />"));
```

Comment: This did it! I'm not sure what it was matching but replacing the `.` with `\w` fixed it!

Comment: @Chris Patten: `.` matches any character (including white space), whereas `\w` matches alphanumeric. It does sound like you've got a lot of redundant white space in there so it may be worth following some of the other suggestions and cleaning that up too.

Answer (score 3):

Try trimming your text, as those could be whitespaces:

```
$(this).html(jQuery.trim($(this).text()).replace(/(.{1})/g, "$1<br />"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a bunch of leading and trailing whitespace coming back from `.text`. You should strip off the whitespace before inserting your `<br>` tags:

```
var $this = $(this);
var t  = $this.text().replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '');
$this.html(t.replace(/(.{1})/g, "$1<br />"));
```

Or a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LAH99/

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to make your code unclear with regex so I wrote a version with String.split() and Array.join()

```
var $this = $(this);
var text = $(this).text();
var arr = text.split('');
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++ ) {
    arr[ i ] += '<br />';
}
$this.text( arr.join('') );
```